# Use stripe to give the payment but responsing the error 404 wiht react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, stripe-payments

I want to have a window for cart.When the button is got tapped,it came a window for payment.
**Expectation:For progressing success,it redirect to the ("/success").In actual,it didn't do it.**
I use the stripe for payment,it appears the errors like that:

*Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()*
*GET https://checkout.stripe.com/v3/data/zipCodes/TW.json?crossDomain=true 404*

Does someone know how to solve the problem?

I checked the network but it also shows the error
[image]

Here are the codes:

Cart.jsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useSelector } from "react-redux"
import StripeCheckout from "react-stripe-checkout"
import { useNavigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from "axios";
import CategoriesItems from '../components/categories/CategoriesItems';
const KEY = "pk_test_51LmJsQKJQzZib5.....rM6";

const Cart = () => {
    const { state } = useLocation();
    const cart = useSelector(state => state.cart);
    const [stripeToken, setStripeToken] = useState(null);
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const onToken = (token) => {
        setStripeToken(token);

    }
    useEffect(() => {

        const makeRequest = async () => {
            try {
                const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:8000/api/checkout/pay", 
                {
                    tokenId: stripeToken.id,
                    amount: cart.total * 100,
                })
                navigate("/success", {
                    state: {
                        stripeData: res.data,
                        products: cart
                    }
                });

            } catch { console.log(5)}
        }
        stripeToken && cart.total > 1 && makeRequest();
    }, [stripeToken, cart.total, navigate]);

    return (
      
              
                    <Summary><SummaryTitle>order summary</SummaryTitle>
                        <SummaryItem>
                            <SummaryItemText>Subtotal</SummaryItemText>
                            <SummaryItemPrice>${cart.total}</SummaryItemPrice>

                        </SummaryItem>
                        <SummaryItem>
                            <SummaryItemText>Estimated Shopping</SummaryItemText>
                            <SummaryItemPrice>$5</SummaryItemPrice>

                        </SummaryItem>
                        <SummaryItem>
                            <SummaryItemText>Shipping Discount</SummaryItemText>
                            <SummaryItemPrice>$ -5.90</SummaryItemPrice>

                        </SummaryItem>
                        <SummaryItem type="total">
                            <SummaryItemText >Total</SummaryItemText>
                            <SummaryItemPrice>${cart.total}</SummaryItemPrice>

                        </SummaryItem>
                        <StripeCheckout
                            name="Fashino on me"
                            billingAddress
                            shippingAddress
                            description={`Your total is $${cart.total}`}
                            amount={cart.total * 100}
                            token={onToken}
                            stripeKey={KEY}>
                            <Button>Checkout now</Button>

                        </StripeCheckout>

                    </Summary>



    )
}

export default Cart
```

Comment: Are you based in Taiwan? Is you Stripe account based in Taiwan? The reason I'm asking you about this, is because the error you're getting the 404 Not found error is because the url you shared is trying to get the zipCodes of TW(Taiwan) which is not a country where Stripe is available. check https://stripe.com/global for a list of available countries.

Comment: @Tarzan I am in Taiwan,so you mean I cannot use the zip code or stripe?

Comment: where is your Stripe account based?

Comment: @Tarzan My account is based on Taiwan.

Comment: That's not possible, Stripe isn't available in Taiwan. In all cases, the library you're using `react-stripe-checkout` is a wrapper of Stripe's [Legacy Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/legacy-checkout) which you should avoid using and switch to a server-side [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/quickstart) or [Payment Links](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-links) integration

Comment: @Tarzan okay.But I have to do a payment for my shopping mall.What I gonna do?